# Adding <br/> during handlebars {{#each}}

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I need to be able to add a `<br/>` after every third category. Is there a way to do this without making a new Handlebars Helper? (I am using third-party software which doesn't let me do so.)

```html
{{#if categories}}
<div id="categories">
  {{#each categories}}
  <div class="category" url="{{url}}">
    <div class="category-icon"></div>
    <div class="category-name">{{name}}</div>
    <span class="category-info"></span>
  </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Are you using the `br` tag to break down onto a new line? If so, have you considered doing `#categories .category:nth-of-type(3n + 1) {clear: left;}` or similar? This allows you to use CSS to clear between lines instead of `br` tags, which might be extraneous unless they're part of the content.

Comment: [`{{#each}}` exposes `{{@index}}`](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html).

Comment: @AndréDion I am aware - however I cannot use {{@index}} in a new function/variable without making a new Handlebars Helper.

Comment: @Hans Yes - this is what I'm trying to do. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I have the following in my CSS now:     .category:nth-of-type(3n+1) {clear: left;}      I am unsure why this isn't working :(

Comment: I have also tried: #categories .category:nth-of-type(3n + 1) {clear: left;}